# Showing TFAE for a compact metric space $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $\mu,\mu_n$ Borel finite measures such that $\mu_n(X) \to \mu(X)$. Prove TFAE:

1. $\int f d \mu_n \to \int f d \mu$ for all $f \in C(X)$.
2. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \mu_n(F) \leq \mu(F)$ for all closed $F \subset X$.
3. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf \mu_n(G) \geq \mu(G)$ for all open $G \subset X$.
4. $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu_n(A)=\mu(A)$ whenever $A \subset X$ is Borel and the measure of the boundary is zero.

So for $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ I used the fact that if $X$ has finite measure and the range of the function has min and max values then the integral on the space is bounded below by the min value times the measure of the space and bounded above by the max value times the measure of the space, so let $a \leq f(x) \leq b$ for $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$ and $x \in X$. Then I have

$$a\mu_n(F) - b\mu(F) \leq \int_F f d \mu_n - \int_F f d \mu \leq b \mu_n(F) - a\mu(F).$$

So I get $\mu_n(F) \leq \mu(F)$.

For $(2) \Rightarrow (3)$ I said since $\mu_n(X) \to \mu(X)$, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_1 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that whenever $n \geq N_1$,
$$\mu_n(X)+\epsilon \geq \mu(X).$$

And by part $(2)$ and fact that if $G$ is open, $G^c$ is closed, for every $\epsilon >0$, there is an $N_2 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that whenever $n \geq N_2$,

$$\mu_n(G^c) \leq \mu(G^c)+\epsilon.$$

Thus

$$\epsilon + \mu_n(X)-\mu_n(G^c) \geq \mu(X)-\mu(G^c).$$

But $\mu(X)-\mu(G^c)$ is $\mu(G)$ and same for $\mu_n$ thus $\mu_n(G) \geq \mu(G)$ and $\epsilon$ was arbitrary and we have $(3)$. I am having a tough time with $(3) \Rightarrow (4)$ and $(4) \Rightarrow (1)$. I figured the standard method of showing TFAE's is to go from one to the next that way you get all equivalences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a) implies (b):

I claim for any closed $F \subset X$ and any finite Borel measure $\nu$ that

$$\nu(F):=\inf \{\int f d \nu: f \in C(X), f \geq \chi_F\}.$$

Clearly, if $f \geq \chi_F$, then $\nu(F) \leq \int f d \nu$, it remains to show the other inequality. For any $G \supset F$ open, there exists $f \in C(X)$ such that $f(x) \in [0,1]$ and $f=1$ on $F$ and $0$ on $G^c$, thus

\begin{align}
\inf_{f \geq \chi_F} \int f d \nu &\leq\inf_{G \supset F, \text{$G$ open}} \nu(G)\\
&=\nu(F).
\end{align}
And our claim is proven. So let $F \subset X$ be closed. Then

\begin{align}
\mu(F)&=\inf_{f \geq \chi_F}\{\int f d \mu\} &&\text{by our claim}\\
&=\inf_{f \geq \chi_F} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f d \mu_n && \text{by (a)}.
\end{align}

But

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f d \mu_n&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup \int f d\mu_n\\
&\geq\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \mu_n(F).
\end{align}

and we are done. Someone besides me upvote this if it’s correct !